# getElementsAtEventForMode() of chartJS 3.0

Tags: chart.js, chart.js3

I'm trying to get elements on click event.
Both line and bar data can be null.

My question is getElementsAtEventForMode() is not working as expected When line data is null.

```
// Same result.
const elements = myChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(e, 'index', { intersect: false }, false);
const element1 = myChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(e, 'nearest', { intersect: false, axis: 'x' }, false);
```

Please check attached image for detail (where I clicked on chart area).

Can I get some help for this issue?

https://codepen.io/wsjraphael/pen/VwyOXdL

[image]